# How to solve 'Undefined Index' Error from <input type="radio">?

Tags: php, html, radio-button

> Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\simv1\register.php
>   on line 409

This my code so far :

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   $a = $_POST['gender'];
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO register SET gender='$a');
}

?>
```

I've put `if(isset())` on my PHP code but it not working.

I've read on Google before, I still confused. Can someone explain the problem with the solution?

Comment: yeps, i not write here. but in my case using form @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Prove it. Every question needs a *testcase*. For example, not having a form can cause this problem, so my having to rule that out with you was a wasted step. I still can't see that you've done it *correctly* (and the fact that your program is broken suggests that you haven't!) so why would you hide that code from us?

Comment: @RN Huh? That's patently untrue! I can critique your answer just fine without writing one of my own. We actually have insufficient information in this question, so I voted to close rather than answering. Still, I think it's important to dispel myths and misinformation posted by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to go. Also please do not use mysql as it is deprecated. Try using mysqli, or even PDO (I like PDO better).

Also, your SQL query is looking odd, so I have updated them as well.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['gender'])) {

$a = $_POST['gender']; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO register (gender) VALUES ('".$a."'"); //for insert

mysql_query("UPDATE register SET gender = '".$a."'"); // for update & don't forget to add the WHERE clause to avoid updating every record

} else {

$a = '';

}

?>
```

Comment: why using `$a = '';` ?
is that for returning a $_POST['gender'] null? @Alex

Comment: That sentence about IDs is nonsense

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit wasn't sure about it - now removed. BogelDR $a = ''; can simply be ignored with the whole else case, it was just to demonstrate how this would build up.

Comment: This answer still does not describes why Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\simv1\register.php on line 409 is coming.